# Run for loop in double dimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi is it possible to run a `for` loop over my `Matrix` list? 
I tried `Matrix [o + for i in range 4]`, but it didn't work.

```
for i in range(col):
    for o in range(row):
        if Matrix[o][i] == "X" and Matrix[o + for i in range 4][i] == "X":
            return True
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What problem do you have exactly? What are you trying to do? What 'is not working'?

Comment: I try to check if 5 symbols in my List are equl to X and i really dont want to make condition long so i want to know if i can do it by loop i mean this Matrix[o + for i in range 4][i] == "X" instead of this  Matrix[o][i] == "X" and  Matrix[o+1][i] == "X" and  Matrix[o+2][i] == "X" and  Matrix[o+3][i] == "X" ...

Comment: What do you expect this to do?  Would `all(Matrix[o+x][i]=='X' for x in range(4))` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Matrix[o + for i in range 4]` is nonsensical. If your goal is to check that at least five symbols in a given "column" are equal to `X`, the solution is to count them up and compare:

```
for i in range(col):
    # booleans have numeric value of 1/0 for True/False, so sum works on them
    if sum(r[i] == 'X' for r in Matrix) >= 5:
        return True
```

If there must be five such symbols in a row, the code is a little more complex (because iterating over slices of a `list` is annoying):

```
for i in range(col):
    for o in range(row):
        rows = Matrix[o:o+5]  # Slice out five consecutive rows
        # Check if given column in all five is X
        if all(r[i] == 'X' for r in rows):
            return True
```

This is slightly inefficient (in that it repeatedly slices and rechecks five elements at a time, even if we could know with certainty that such a run could not occur), but likely acceptable unless the code is in a hot loop and absolutely critical to performance. The only way you could get improved performance without complicating things would be if the matrix was guaranteed to contain exactly one character in each cell, in which case the code could simplify to:

```
for i in range(col):
    # Get characters from each cell in column, join to single string
    colstr = ''.join([r[i] for r in Matrix])
    if 'XXXXX' in colstr:  # Scan string once (pushes all work to C, should be fast)
        return True
```

Comment: This is solution for my tic tac toe and i want to check if there are 5 same characters in cross. Do you know how i can achive it easily or i need to run another loop and check all symbols separately.

Comment: also if i want same condition for row. Your solution wokrs only for collums